# Trying to add a delete record function to my web app that uses XRM tooling to update/edit records in Dynamics 365 and keep getting this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

This is the error I'm currently getting

[image: This is the error I'm currently getting]

I'll add more screenshots of my delete code that it connects to below:

The string id connects it to the specific record that I click delete next to.

Below is the code in the CommonServices.cs:

```
public bool DeleteEmployeeRecord(new_EmploymentHubCollegues employmentHubCollegue)
{
    CrmServiceClient serviceClient = GetCrmServiceClient();
    
    serviceClient.Delete(employmentHubCollegue);

    return true;
}
```

Below is the code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteEmployee(string id)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application edit page.";

    new_EmploymentHubCollegues Delete = _Service.GetCollegue(id);

    return View(Delete);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteEmployee(new_EmploymentHubCollegues Delete)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application edit page.";

    if (_Service.DeleteEmployeeRecord(Delete) == true)
    {

    }

    return View(Delete);
}
```

below is the code in my services.cs

```
bool DeleteEmployeeRecord(new_EmploymentHubCollegues employmentHubCollegue);
```

The code I have above works when it comes to updating or adding a new record (obviously different variable names etc.). I'm just not sure how to do the delete function. Maybe it doesn't need to be a bool ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to fulfill CrmServiceClient.Delete method signature -> it accepts two parameters, not one. First one is entity logical name and second one is the ID of the entity.

I guess that new_EmploymentHugCollegues is early bound entity generated via crmsvcutil.exe, so you can easily modify your method to this:

```
public bool DeleteEmployeeRecord(new_EmploymentHubCollegues employmentHubCollegue)
{
    CrmServiceClient serviceClient = GetCrmServiceClient();
    
    serviceClient.Delete(employmentHubCollegue.LogicalName, employmentHubCollegue.Id);

    return true;
}
```